# What does “standard including equipment” mean for a monster's treasure entry?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, treasure

Looking at the Harpy Archer treasure description it reads

> Standard including equipment

Does this mean that the treasure includes the +3 studded leather, +1 frost composite longbow (+1 Str bonus), 10 cold iron arrows, 10 silvered arrows, 5 +2 arrows, lesser bracers of archery, potion of cure moderate wounds, potion of cat’s grace, cloak of resistance +2, and ring of protection +1 listed in the creatures possessions in addition to the standard treasure for a CR 11 monster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* on Monsters with Classes says says

> Many monsters advance by adding class levels…. **To determine treasure for monsters with class levels, first give them equipment.** Use Table 4–23: NPC Gear Value (page 127) and use just their class levels to determine the value of their equipment. **Then generate their treasure according to their monster entry and the rules** under Building a Treasure, below. This may generate more items that the monster can use, and that’s fine…. (51)

(Emphasis mine.) In other words, the [harpy](http://dndsrd.net/monstersHtoI.html#harpy) fighter 7 has gear that's appropriate for a level 7 NPC *plus*, typically, sitting around, there's *also* the treasure that's appropriate for the encounter level of the encounter in which the harpy fighter 7 appears. However, a DM isn't *required* to include extra treasure beyond the monster's personal gear (yet he *should* if the encounter is also with, for example, a harpy fighter 7 and a bunch more harpies with no class levels!). The *Dungeon Master's Guide* in NPCs and Treasure explains

> The gear that NPCs carry serves as the bulk of their treasure. The average value of an NPC’s gear is listed on Table 4–23: NPC Gear Value, and examples of what specific gear a character of a given class and level would have are in the sample NPC descriptions in Chapter 4. **NPCs may have treasure in addition to their gear, *at your discretion***, but an NPC’s gear is already worth about three times the average value of a treasure of his or her level. Defeating NPC foes brings about great reward for treasure-seekers, but since the gear is mostly magic that the NPC can use against the characters (some of which is one-use), it all evens out. (55)

(Emphases mine.) In other words, the DM can opt for *no* even greater reward *if* monsters with class levels have enough cool stuff already. Fortunately it's not a worry here, but this *does* get a little more complicated if a spellbook's involved—a spellbook's value is specifically subtracted from an encounter's (extra) treasure (*DMG* 54). (Note that the *Dungeon Master's Guide* and the *Monster Manual* have different formulas for determining a monster with class levels's effective level therefore exactly *how much* wealth it should have; see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/31505/8610).)

Comment: I was just surprised because the average treasure for a CR 11 encounter and the treasure presented for this harpy are so vastly different. The average treasure for a CR 11 encounter is around 7500gp but this harpy has around 25,000gp worth of equipment.

Comment: Yeah, I've no idea how the *MM* assigns gear. My answer [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/49109/8610) might provide some insight into that discrepancy. (The *DMG* says the harpy archer should have 7,200 gp in gear, and the *MM* says it should have 100,000 gp in gear—and, of course, in actual practice, the game does neither and seems to base gear on the creature's CR.)

Answer (score 2):

"Standard including equipment" means that equipment is included in the standard treasure parcel.

In other words you should calculate the value of the equipment and add more money (or valuables) until you reach the value of a standard trasure.